# How to run multiple stream analysis in real time using yolov8?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pyqt5, yolov8

I have a python code with opencv and pyqt5, where the user sends the video to the platform and it is displayed being processed using yolov8. currently it processes one code and when finished it starts processing the other. I need to make them work in parallel and in a "dynamic" way, as it is software that will run on the client's machine and it will work on the interface, not on the code... How can I process these videos in parallel with yolov8 in Python?

i hope someone could help me find the solution

Comment: Can you clarify: what computer is the yolov8 processing happening on? Are you asking for help with the client half, the server half, or both?